# how to give dynamic values to chart from controller to view in code igniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

the following is the code am having.in this code am giving values statically. now what i need to do is i need to get the dynamic values and the chart has to be displayed.here into the items variable i have to get the values in the same way from the controller and the chart has to be displayed.thanks.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 355px;"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var chart;

var chartData = [{
    year: "FY 2011-12",
    visits: 3025
    },
{
    year: "FY 2011-12",
    visits: 1882
    },
{
    year: "FY 2011-12",
    visits: 1809
    },
{
    year: "FY 2011-12",
    visits: 1322
    }
    }];


AmCharts.ready(function() {
    // SERIAL CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.autoMarginOffset = 0;
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "year";
    chart.startDuration = 1;
    chart.depth3D = 20;
    chart.angle = 30;

    // AXES
    // category
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.labelRotation = 45; // this line makes category values to be rotated
    categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
    categoryAxis.fillAlpha = 1;
    categoryAxis.fillColor = "#FAFAFA";
    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

    // value
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.dashLength = 5;
    valueAxis.title = "Visitors from country";
    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

    // GRAPH
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.valueField = "visits";
    graph.colorField = "color";
    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.fillAlphas = 1;
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");
});
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The CodeIgniter documentation explains this very clearly.

Comment: in controller i gave in this way function chartvalues(){
     $funds = array (
 '0' => array (
 'Date' => '9-3-00',
 'Value' => 6
 ),
 '1' => array (
 'Date' => '9-3-00',
 'Value' => 10
 ),
 '2' => array (
 'Date' => '9-3-00',
 'Value' => 20
 ),
 );
 echo json_encode($funds);
 }and in this view file i gave as follows var values;
 $.ajax({
   cache : false,
   type: "POST",
   url: 'chartvalues',
   success: function(response)
   {
    values = response;
    //alert (values);
    }
   
  }); inside ajax am getting the values into var values but after ajax it is not getting any values.so i asked

Comment: The CodeIgniter user guide is a good starting point. It explains exactly how to pass data from controllers to views. [Read about it here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can collect all value in an array on controller after that on view page you can call it like :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 355px;"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var chart;

var chartData = [{
    year: "<?php echo $date1;?>",
    visits: "<?php echo $date1visitval;?>"
    },
{
    year: "<?php echo $date2;?>",
    visits: "<?php echo $date2visitval;?>"
    },
{
    year:  "<?php echo $date4;?>",
    visits: "<?php echo $date3visitval;?>"
    },
{
    year:  "<?php echo $date4;?>",
    visits: "<?php echo $date4visitval;?>"
    }
    }];


AmCharts.ready(function() {
    // SERIAL CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.autoMarginOffset = 0;
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "year";
    chart.startDuration = 1;
    chart.depth3D = 20;
    chart.angle = 30;

    // AXES
    // category
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.labelRotation = 45; // this line makes category values to be rotated
    categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
    categoryAxis.fillAlpha = 1;
    categoryAxis.fillColor = "#FAFAFA";
    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

    // value
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.dashLength = 5;
    valueAxis.title = "Visitors from country";
    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

    // GRAPH
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.valueField = "visits";
    graph.colorField = "color";
    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]";
    graph.type = "column";
    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.fillAlphas = 1;
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv");
});
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: how to give array in controller so that to call in the above manner

Comment: if am having more data i can't give for eveything like this right so any other solution to this using ajax

Comment: You can get value from db in controller, and make it in array format.

Comment: yeah i have tried it in the following. 
in controller i gave in this way function chartvalues(){ $funds = array ( '0' => array ( 'Date' => '9-3-00', 'Value' => 6 ), '1' => array ( 'Date' => '9-3-00', 'Value' => 10 ), '2' => array ( 'Date' => '9-3-00', 'Value' => 20 ), ); echo json_encode($funds); }and in this view file i gave as follows var values; $.ajax({ cache : false, type: "POST", url: 'chartvalues', success: function(response) { values = response; //alert (values); } }); inside ajax am getting the values into var values but after ajax it is not getting any values.so i asked.

Comment: Now From controller you can pass $funds into a separate variable from controller to view. and make a for loop for var chartData into javascript.

Comment: Sorry, Try it your self. You have another method also, you can put all javascript into a variable on controller and loop for var chardata. This will also work.

Comment: please prasannjit i require it and also am new to this code igniter so am asking you

Comment: <?php
  for($i=0;$i<count($six_year);$i++) {
  
   ?>
var chartData = [{
    year: "<?php echo $six_year[$i]['year']; ?>",
    visits: 3025
    }];
<?php }
   //$this->total_change = $row['total']/100;
    ?>
i have given in this way but am getting only one value

Comment: var chartData =  use for loop here{}

Comment: same output is getting that is only one value is displaying

Comment: Please concatenate value behind loop

Comment: that means how to do that prasannjit.

Comment: hi, prasannjit get me some solution to handle this